# I am unable to build my flutter web project

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When trying to run `flutter build web` i get "build web" is not currently supported.
I had previous errors where i was stuck with `Dart 2.5.0-dev.4.0.flutter-be66176534` and required 2.5.0 or higher, this has now been solved but i am unable to build my project.

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18932.1000], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (8 days ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\germa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\germa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.4.1
```

I have tried

- re-installing dart
- re-installing flutter
- re-installing Visual Studio code
- copy file contents to a new web project (same error)

I couldn't find any information on what this is caused by and how to resolve it online

What can i do to resolve this error?

Comment: Create a new project for this problem.
Maybe you try to run an old project.

Answer (score 30):

Please once do configure like below

1. `flutter channel stable`
2. `flutter upgrade`
3. `flutter config --enable-web`
4. `cd` into project directory
5. `flutter create .`
6. `flutter run -d chrome`

Comment: Hi, i have done this, however now i get
`Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).`
Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: It work for me but at last face character issue, so install "characters 1.0.0" dependency. https://pub.dev/packages/characters#-installing-tab-
Github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59645

Answer (score 8):

So currently you are at stable channel . You have to switch to the beta channel as flutter web is not at a stable channel right now. In order to make it working run the following commands in the terminal.

1. flutter channel beta
2. flutter upgrade
3. flutter config --enable-web.

   After that restart your IDE and build the web app.

Comment: This works for me - the official docs are [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing problem in flutter stable 2.0.2, by running

```
flutter create .
```

it was not creating web module, after upgrading it has started working. I guess my flutter web sdk had some issue so by fresh upgrade it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if your are facing the problem

> Ambiguous organization in existing files: {package_name1, package_name2}. The --org command line argument must be specified to recreate project.

you can use this command

```
flutter create --org package_name1 .
```

And

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you have used any plugins in pubspecs.yaml that is nonweb supportive.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add web support to an existing app:

```
flutter create .
```

then try to

```
flutter build web
```